# Kendo DropDown List OnChange event does not work

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, onchange

Here is my Kendo Drop Down List:

```
function modelProducer(container, options) {
    $('<input  name="ModelProducer"  data-type="string"\">')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: modelProducerResult,
            dataTextField: "model",
            dataValueField: "model",
        });

}
```

Here is the OnChange event which cant get the value of of my drop down
 list upon changing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function onSelect(e) {
        if ("#DeviceType" in window) {
            if (e.item) {
                var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
                kendoConsole.log("event :: select (" + dataItem.text + " : " + dataItem.value + ")");
            } else {
                kendoConsole.log("event :: select");
            }
        }
    }
    debugger;
});
```

Comment: are you sure the "if ("#DeviceType" in window) {" is correct ? and then add it: .kendoDropDownList({  select: onSelect(e) })

Comment: @Ciccio what I found in kendo document is if("kendoConsole")...but here my kendo drop down list has an id,which is #deviceType not sure what should I write there

Answer (score 1):

Change your code, with select event

```
function modelProducer(container, options) {
    $('<input  name="ModelProducer"  data-type="string"\">')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: modelProducerResult,
            dataTextField: "model",
            dataValueField: "model",
           select: onSelect(e)
        });

}
```

and then change the control that has no sense. You want to check if "id" is in the window object.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function onSelect(e) {

            if (e.item) {
                var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
                kendoConsole.log("event :: select (" + dataItem.text + " : " + dataItem.value + ")");
            } else {
                kendoConsole.log("event :: select");
            }

    }
});
```

Comment: where should I put my Ajax?

Comment: Study the base of javascript!! For now write select: function(e){

            if (e.item) {
                var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
                kendoConsole.log("event :: select (" + dataItem.text + " : " + dataItem.value + ")");
            } else {
                kendoConsole.log("event :: select");
            }

Comment: Hi @ciccio, do you have any thing about, I have the same thing happened in my code